# django : How can I display the list of images of an album?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I create an album model, and an Image model, one album can have lot of image.
How can I do to display in the JSON response (of album) the list of images containing in the album ?

this is my models :

```
class Album(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title


class AlbumImage(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=upload_path_image)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self): 
         return self.title
```

Comment: How about When serializing Album object, pull out all AlbumImage objects associated with it, and serialize them as a list.

Comment: how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the `related_name` in the `album` field.

```
class AlbumImage(models.Model):
     ...
     album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name = "images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

And in the Album serializer, you can set the images attribute using the AlbumImage serializer.

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = AlbumImageSerializer(read_only = True, many = True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'images')
        model = Album
```